# How can I implement single table inheritance using Laravel's Eloquent?

Tags: mysql, inheritance, laravel, eloquent, subclass

Currently I have a model class named `Post`.

```
class Post extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'posts';
    protected $fillable = array('user_id', 'title', 'description', 'views');

    /*
     * Relationships
     */

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }

    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Tag', 'post_tags');
    }

    public function reactions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Reaction');
    }

    public function votes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('PostVote');
    }

    //Scopes and functions...
}
```

I would like to divide posts into two different types; `articles` and `questions`. I thought the best way to do this is by inheritance, so `Article` and `Question` would extend `Post`. What is the best way to do this and where to start?

Comment: In the database it still would be one table? (and for example a column that defines the type)

Comment: Sorry, I was so confused! Adding a `type` column in the posts table is enough since there are no differences between articles and questions. The only thing is that articles have a thumbnail image, but I could leave that column `NULL` for questions (right?).

Comment: Yes, if it's only one column that differs, I'd say its totally ok to just leave it null. However if this changes you might want to split it up into multiple tables to reduce unused columns.
So now, do you still need help with your question or are you going to work with the Post model alone?

Comment: Yes I would love to hear your answer as the only difference might not be the thumbnail column. I need this for further development.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Before I dig into *multi table* inheritance I want to lose a few words about *single table* inheritance. Single table inheritance is the more easy way when it comes to inheritance with db models.
You have multiple models bound to the same table and a `type` column to distinguish between the different model classes. However the reason you normally want to implement inheritance is because the models have shared properties but also some that are unique to the model.
When using single table inheritance your table looks similar to that at some point:

```
id   shared_column   question_column   article_column   question_column2   article_column2 etc...
1    Lorem           62                NULL             test               NULL
2    Ipsum           NULL              x                NULL               true
```

You end up having a lot of NULL values because there are columns not needed for a certain type of model. And with a lot of records this can influence the size of database.

However for some cases it might still be the best solution. Here's a well written [Tutorial](http://codebyjeff.com/blog/2014/07/single-table-inheritence-in-laravel) that shows how to implement it in Laravel in a pretty elegant way.

### Multi Table Inheritance

Now lets look at multi table inheritance. With this method you split your single table into multiple ones (well I guess the name gave that kind of away already ;)) We are going to use a technique called [Polymorphism](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#polymorphic-relations)

Our schema from the example above would look like this:

```
posts table:

id   shared_column  postable_id  postable_type
1    Lorem          1            Question
2    Ipsum          1            Article


questions table:

id   question_column   question_column2
1    62                test


articles table:

id   article_column   article_column2
1    x                true
```

A lot cleaner if you ask me...

The interesting columns here are `postable_id` and `postable_type`. The type tells us on which table we will find our "rest" of the model and the id specifies the primary key of the record that belongs to it. Note that the column names could be whatever you want, but it is convention to call it *"-able"*.

Lets take a look at the Eloquent models now.

**Post**

```
class Post extends Eloquent {
    // all your existing code
    
    public function postable(){
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

**Question** / **Article** / **every other postable type**

```
class Question extends Post {
    public function post(){
        return $this->morphOne('Post', 'postable');
    }
}
```

Note that you actually don't have to extend from `Post` but you can if you maybe have methods that you want to use too. Anyways, the polymorphic relationship will work with or without it.

Ok that's the basic setup. Here's how you can use your new models:

**Retrieve all posts**

```
$posts = Post::all();
```

**Retrieve all questions**

```
$questions = Question::all();
```

**Get question columns from a post**

```
$post = Post::find(1);
$question_column2 = $post->postable->question_column2;
```

**Get post properties from question**

```
$question = Question::find(1);
$shared_column = $question->post->shared_column;
```

**Check which type a post is**

```
$post = Post::find(1);
echo 'type: '.get_class($post->postable);
if($post->postable instanceof Question){
    // Looks like we got a question here
}
```

**Create new question**

Now bear with me, creating a model is a bit more complicated. If you have to do it at multiple places in your application I suggest you write a reusable function for it.

```
// create a record in the questions and posts table

$question = new Question();
$question->question_column = 'test';
$question->save();

$post = new Post();
$post->shared_column = 'New Question Post';
$post->save();

// link them together

$question->post()->save($post);
```

So as you can see, a clean database comes with it's price. It will be a bit more complex to handle your model. However you can put all these extra logic (e.g. that's required to create a model) into a function in your model class and don't worry about it too much.

Also, there's a nice [Tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20150217020611/http://www.richardbagshaw.co.uk/laravel-user-types-and-polymorphic-relationships/) for multi table inheritance with laravel too. Maybe it helps ;)

Comment: This is brilliant, clear and more then I could have asked for. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're very welcome. I hope this answer also helps other people in the future :)

Comment: I've been looking all over for a multi-table inheritance example. Was so stuck in the symfony style of thinking I didn't realize you could leverage polymorphic relationships to emulate the behavior. Thanks!

Comment: This response inspired me on coding a way to automate and simplify the process of writing an object through many tables, implementing model inheritance by laravel polymorphic relations. I would be glad to hear your opinion about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48445727/laravel-model-inheritance-through-polymorphic-relation

Comment: @lukasgeiter This is nice until you need to delete a Post. Because the relationship is inversed, when you delete a Question, of course the Post will be deleted. But what if we delete the Post? When we delete the Post, whatever associated to it, whether it's Question or Article should be deleted. How do you handle it?

Comment: The NULL values issue is possibly less significant nowadays compared to when this answer was written because you can potentially create a JSON field to store attributes specific to content types and support for JSON fields is pretty common now in relational databases.

Answer (score 8):

from Laravel 5.2, `Global Scope` is available:

```
class Article extends Post
{
    protected $table = 'posts';

    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::addGlobalScope('article', function (Builder $builder) {
            $builder->where('type', 'article');
        });

        static::creating(function ($article) {
            $article->type = 'article' 
        }); 
    }
}
```

`where type = 'article'` is added to all query of `Article` just like `SoftDeletes`.

```
>>> App\Article::where('id', 1)->toSql()
=> "select * from `posts` where `id` = ? and `type` = ?"
```

Actually laravel provide `SoftDeletes` trait using this feature.

Comment: My guess would be that your code will do fine at selections, but for the creation of new Articles, it'll need some extra work...

Comment: Yeah, we should hook `creating` like this

```
    static::creating(function ($article) {
        $article->type = 'article'
    });
```

Comment: I added `static::creating` to my answer.