# how to implement sub model in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

my base class is post
and many submodel such as : video post , image post 
all class have specific attribute & inherit parent attrib
& all class need specific behaviors

**Problem**

when find on post model elequent give super model(post) instance, its wrong 
i need instance of submodel

Comment: It is very unclear what you want to do. Please provide some more info and code examples.

Comment: And your models look like..?

Comment: I want inheritance sub model from model?

Comment: basically a model that shares attribute but had more details added on child model? this could be done several ways, simple eloquent (still uses **single main model**) or single table inheritance (uses **several main model** on one table).

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you need relationships

Add a `hasMany` relationship to your `Post.php` model:

```
public function videos()
    return $this->hasMany(App\PostVideo::class);
}
```

As long as your `post_video` table has a `post_id` column that references a post, you can call this relationship like this:

```
foreach($post->videos as $video) {
    // Do something
}
```

**And the inverse relationship:**

Add a relationship to your `PostVideo.php` model:

```
public function post() {
    return $this->belongsTo(App\Post::class);
}
```

And of course, if you have a video, you can access the post it belongs to by doing:

```
$video->post
```

Answer (score 0):

It is looked like you want a [single table inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_Table_Inheritance). In laravel this could be done manually or use package like [nanigans](https://github.com/Nanigans/single-table-inheritance) or [intrip](https://github.com/intrip/laravel-single-table-inheritance). To use single table inheritance manually, i could suggest you start with reading [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26691577/laravel-eloquent-single-table-inheritance) first. However, notice that single table inheritance put **everything** in a single table  but refered by several models that have different behavior. If this is not what you want, just use simple eloquent queries and models - which already explained by Pistachio.